# How to connect a swift app to a socket io server

Tags: node.js, swift, socket.io

I am trying to connect my swift app to my web socket backend. On my backend I am using node, express and socket.io. My server is running correctly and I am able to connect to it and use the web sockets from my react web app. I am struggling to achieve the same result with swift. I am using socket.io-client-swift library to connect. My server is secure, I will used `https://test.api.com` as my address for this.

My socket connection in my react app looks as follows:

```
const socket = io('https://test.api.com', {
  secure: true,
  forceNew: true,
  reconnectionAttempts: 'Infinity',
  timeout: 30000,
  transports: ['websocket']
})
```

My swift connection code looks as follows:

```
class Socket: NSObject {

    static let shared = Socket()

    override init() {
        super.init()

        let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "https://test.api.com")!)
        manager.setConfigs([.secure(true), .log(true)])

        log.warning("Setting up socket connection")
        let socket = manager.defaultSocket

        socket.on(clientEvent: .connect) {data, ack in
            log.warning("Socket connected")
        }

        log.warning("Connecting...")
        socket.connect(timeoutAfter: 15) {
            log.warning("Can't connect to socket server")
        }        
    }

}
```

My error log looks like this:

```
LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: statusChange with data: [connecting, 2]
LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Joining namespace /
LOG SocketManager: Tried connecting socket when engine isn't open. Connecting
LOG SocketManager: Adding engine
LOG SocketManager: Manager is being released
LOG SocketEngine: Starting engine. Server: https://test.api.com
LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Client is being released
LOG SocketEngine: Handshaking
LOG SocketEnginePolling: Doing polling GET https://test.api.com/socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1
ERROR SocketEnginePolling: Error during long poll request
ERROR SocketEngine: Error
LOG SocketEngine: Engine is being released
```

My server initialisation for the socket looks as follows:

```
// Add websocket
var allowedOrigins = "http://localhost:*";
const socketConfig = {
  origins: allowedOrigins,
  pingTimeout: 60000
}
io = require('socket.io')(server, socketConfig);
```

Comment: are you sure, there is no extra namespace?

Comment: Yes. In my react app I have added no extra namespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue. On the server I was only allowing localhost in the socket config. This worked on the react app as it was running locally. When I removed the origins everything worked correctly. The socket server initialization looks as follws:

```
// Add websocket
var allowedOrigins = "http://localhost:*";
const socketConfig = {
  // origins: allowedOrigins, -- Removed this line
  pingTimeout: 60000
}
io = require('socket.io')(server, socketConfig);
```